# How to make my batch file execute both programs

Tags: batch-file, execute

```
@ECHO OFF
:EXECUTE
"C:\Users\Lake\Desktop\New folder\Executes\spotify.bat"
:EXECUTE
"C:\Users\Lake\Desktop\New Folder\Executes\Firefox.bat"
```

That is what is in my batch file. It only executes the first one and I want it to execute both. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the two `:EXECUTE` labels and use `CALL`, so it returns to the current batch file after it executes the `CALL`ed one:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL "C:\Users\Lake\Desktop\New folder\Executes\spotify.bat"
CALL "C:\Users\Lake\Desktop\New Folder\Executes\Firefox.bat"
```

Comment: That's not possible, unless the first one doesn't exist where you've said it is (in the `CALL` command).

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want them to execute asynchronously, you can use START instead of CALL:

```
@ECHO OFF
START "C:\Users\Lake\Desktop\New folder\Executes\spotify.bat"
START "C:\Users\Lake\Desktop\New Folder\Executes\Firefox.bat"
```